# Why my Alarm is fired earlier than my set time?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm currently trying to make an alarm app that will mute all audio volume at the user-defined day and time. However, the alarm seems not fired at the correct time. I found that the alarm is always fired earlier.

This is my set alarm code:

```
public static void setAlarm(Context context, String time, int day, int reqCode) {
    String[] timeSplit = time.split(":");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hour = Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[0]);
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[1]);
    int days = (day-calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    calendar.set(
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            days,
            hour,
            minute,
            0
    );

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RuleAlarm.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, reqCode, intent, 0);

    // Set the alarm to be fired every week on the selected day
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have tried to change `setRepeating()` to `setInexactRepeating()` but nothing changed.

Comment: how much earlier is your alarm being triggered?

Comment: about 2 minutes after it set. I have tested on the same and different day.

Comment: did you debug and check what value you are getting in `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` while you are setting alarm.

Comment: Yup, it's 1.5 billion milliseconds. It seems that I have found the problem after debugging the `days` variable. I will post the answer if it worked.

Comment: try converting the millis value you will get exact time. https://currentmillis.com/

Comment: I got this result, Mon May 06 2019 07:17:00. After I added 1 to the `day` variable, the result is the same as before but it seems working. I added 1 because the spinner index starts from zero while the Calendar day starts from one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out the problem. It lies on the `day` params. What I pass to `day` params is my Spinner selected position which starts from zero while the Calendar days starts from one (SUNDAY = 1, MONDAY = 2, so on). So, the alarm will always be set in the past days. I plus one to the `day` params and it's worked.

This is my piece of code where the `startAlarm()` function got called.

```
String ruleStartTime = rule_startTime.getText().toString();

// Spinner index starts from zero,
// to match with the Calendar day indexing, we need to plus it one
int dayIdx = day.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;

Alarm.setAlarm(getApplicationContext(), ruleStartTime,
                        dayIdx, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

The problem is that if you are creating `PendingIntent` for an alarm for past time it will be fired immediately.If you would like to prevent that happening, then simply do not set alarms with a past trigger time . Use `BroadcastReceiver` for receiving alarm.

**Update :**

Check we aren't setting it in the past which would trigger it to fire instantly

```
    if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems my alarm always set to past days and I'm trying to fix it now. By the way, how do you skip the past alarm and fired it on the next week?

Comment: why you use `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` and set it to 7?

Comment: it  will help you to skip the past alarm and fired it on the next week,calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7) add 7 days with current date

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManger is inexact to save battery by combining wakeup calls. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

[image: Screenshot from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html]